# How can I use an L298N driver with a 3.3v stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

so I'm starting to delve into stepper motors with arduino for a project I'm working on, which is proving interesting so far, with me first getting a motor far too small, and then also finding out that using a stepper motor is a blocking function, and not playing well with my code.

Anyhow, my concern is that all of the beefy nema 17 stepper motors are rated at 3v to 3.5v, the one I'm looking at rated for 3.35v for driving, however, all of the stepper motor drivers I can find capable of 1.5-2 amp loads have a 5 volt output.

I'm not sure if maybe there's just an obscure driver package that outputs a 3.5v signal or something along those lines, but I'm wondering what I need to do to use a 3.3 to 3.5v stepper motor with a 5v driver without burning it out, and likely drawing the full 1.5 or 2 amps that the driver can provide.

Perhaps just a diode with the right level of voltage drop in the correct orientations for each phase? I'll need to be able to move the stepper both directions though so I imagine that wouldn't work.

I did just find [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/6dikhr/l298n_motor_controller_voltage_question/) post however that seems like it might actually be a non issue if I provide the stepper with a 5v or 5.5v supply.

[Link to the motors I plan on using, likely the 48mm](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/263492181830?ul_noapp=true)

Comment: You don't want to exceed the current rating of the motor. The L298N is only an H-bridge, you will want a PWM stepper motor controller also. A good controller should be able to keep the current constant at a desired level. Most are designed to use a large supply voltage and they PWM to get the desired current. Have you picked a controller?

Comment: I was just going to use one of the l298n based drivers that you see on ebay with a decent sized heatsink for a few bucks.